# Where did Ender spend his first month of Earthside leave?

Tags: novel, enders-game, continuity

We know that he spent his last two months in "the house that Medly's Mist-E-Rub built", between [Lake Brandt](https://www.google.com/maps/@36.1640593,-79.8449067,15z) and a "five-acre private lake".

> "You said he built the raft. How long has be been here?"
>
> "Two months. We meant his leave to last only a few days. But you see, he doesn't seem interested in going on with his education."

But he had  a three month leave, as we see from:

> So that's why you brought me here, thought Ender. With all your hurry, that's why you took three months, to make me love Earth. Well, it worked. All your tricks worked. Valentine, too; she was another one of your tricks, to make me remember that I'm not going to school for myself. Well, I remember.

And also from what Admiral Chamrajangar tells Graff:

> "Took your time, didn't you, Graff? The voyage isn't short, but the three month vacation seems excessive."

So where did he spend the first month?

Comment: wow you ask a lot things so... detail, it good to re-read part(s) to find answer (though it always make me feel sad even just think about the book(s)); but this is fiction with a lot event(s) and character(s) so it so hard (if not impossible) to have all things detailed, instead it give something more general, not specific so it easier to remember and avoid conflict in later chapter(s) or book(s); so Ender have 3 months on Earth, last 2 of it he spend near the lake, the first month he can be anywhere doing anything in order to love Earth again

Comment: @HenryVarro It also is possible that the whole of Ender's leave was spent on the lake, and one of those numbers was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually *that clear* how much time passed after Valentine left and the point that Ender "came in the door" to see Graff. It's certainly possible that a significant amount of time (a whole month) passed before his next visit.

> He didn't answer. She doubted that he believed her. She walked back up
>   the hill, savagely angry at them for making her come to Ender like
>   this. For she had, after all, done just what they wanted. She had
>   talked Ender into going back into his training, and he wouldn't soon
>   forgive her for that.
>
> ***[One month later...]*** Ender came in the door, still wet from his last dip in the lake. It
>   was dark outside, and dark in the room where Graff waited for him.
>
> "Are we going now?" asked Ender.